# Inline cast of char types

Tags: casting, type-conversion, abap

Does abap have any method to perform an inline cast for char types (or any similar types of different length)? Perhaps there is something similar to `value` operator( for structures) that can be used for fields.

Concrete example (`name` is of type `tdobname`, which is char 70 and `ebeln` is char 10) that leads to a dump due to type mismatch:

```
call function 'READ_TEXT'
  exporting
    id                      = lv_textid
    language                = sy-langu
    name                    = ls_ekko-ebeln
    object                  = 'EKKO'
  tables
    lines                   = lt_textlines
```

For now I added an line of conversion to a variable of destination type (which works), but I am hoping to skip that step.

```
data: lv_name type tdobname.
lv_name = ls_ekko-ebeln.
call function 'READ_TEXT'
  exporting
    ...
    name                    = lv_name
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CONV](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenconstructor_expression_conv.htm) operator for that:

```
DATA(lv_name) = CONV tdobname( ls_ekko-ebeln ).
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I actually used inline conversion as a parameter (the way you said it wouldn't work). Maybe it's supported in latest version? Anyways, there's a problem with that particular parameter, because numeric keys need to be padded with zeroes and `EBELN` has to be padded (EBELNs that are 10 characters long work, but shorter ones don't).

Comment: I was a bit incorrect, the inline declarations cannot be used during FM calls, whereas CONV operator is acceptable.